# How do the functions work?

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, radix-sort

Could you explain me how  the following two algorithms work?

```
int countSort(int arr[], int n, int exp)
{
    int output[n]; 
    int i, count[n] ;
    for (int i=0; i < n; i++)
       count[i] = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        count[ (arr[i]/exp)%n ]++;
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
        count[i] += count[i - 1];
    for (i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        output[count[ (arr[i]/exp)%n] - 1] = arr[i];
        count[(arr[i]/exp)%n]--;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        arr[i] = output[i];
}


void sort(int arr[], int n)
{
    countSort(arr, n, 1);
    countSort(arr, n, n);
}
```

I wanted to apply the algorithm at this array:

[image]

After calling the function  countSort(arr, n, 1) , we get this:

[image]

When I call then the function countSort(arr, n, n) , at this  for loop:

```
for (i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    output[count[ (arr[i]/exp)%n] - 1] = arr[i];
    count[(arr[i]/exp)%n]--;
}
```

I get output[-1]=arr[4].

But the array doesn't have such a position...

Have I done something wrong?

**EDIT**:Considering the array arr[] = { 10, 6, 8, 2, 3 }, the array count will contain the following elements:

[image]

what do these numbers represent? How do we use them?

Comment: @clcto So should it be like that?

for (i = n - 1; i >= 1; i--)
{
    output[count[ (arr[i]/exp)%n] - 1] = arr[i];
    count[(arr[i]/exp)%n]--;
}

Comment: @clcto Could you explain me how the functions work?

Comment: [Read this for an explanation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort)

Comment: Btw the function looks ok.  What did you pass as `n`?  After the first call, the array should have changed if you used `n` = 5.

Comment: @JS1 The number of occurences of each value is counted and then the counts are accumulated ... Could you explain to me how we then use this array? I haven't understood it...

Comment: What does this mean?

Comment: Concerning edit: these numbers tell us which positions in the sorted array will be occupied by numbers ending with 0, 1, 2, ..., 9 from original array. Reading from left to right: at index 0 we have "numbers ending with 0" will be at positions 0..1, then at index 1 we have the same number as at index 0, which means there were no numbers ending with 1 in the original array. Then, at index 2 we have 2, which means that numbers ending with 2 will be at positions 1..2 and so on. Look at my answer, at the line starting with "Now you know that in a sorted array" for a simplified example of this.

Answer (score 2):

Counting sort is very easy - let's say you have an array which contains numbers from range `1..3`:
`[3,1,2,3,1,1,3,1,2]`

You can count how many times each number occurs in the array:
`count[1] = 4`
`count[2] = 2`
`count[3] = 3`

Now you know that in a sorted array,
number `1` will occupy positions `0..3` (from `0` to `count[1] - 1`), followed by
number `2` on positions `4..5` (from `count[1]` to `count[1] + count[2] - 1`), followed by
number `3` on positions `6..8` (from `count[1] + count[2]` to `count[1] + count[2] + count[3] - 1`).

Now that you know final position of every number, you can just insert every number at its correct position. That's basically what `countSort` function does.

However, in real life your input array would not contain just numbers from range `1..3`, so the solution is to sort numbers on the least significant digit (LSD) first, then LSD-1 ... up to the most significant digit.
This way you can sort bigger numbers by sorting numbers from range `0..9` (single digit range in decimal numeral system).
This code: `(arr[i]/exp)%n` in `countSort` is used just to get those digits. `n` is base of your numeral system, so for decimal you should use `n = 10` and `exp` should start with `1` and be multiplied by base in every iteration to get consecutive digits.
For example, if we want to get third digit from right side, we use `n = 10` and `exp = 10^2`:
`x = 1234`,
`(x/exp)%n = 2`.

This algorithm is called Radix sort and is explained in detail on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort

Comment: While your general background explanation is good, as a general rule, you do not answer questions on **SO** by referring the questioner to a remote site. That is basically the same as saying **the explanation can be found there, you go figure it out**. What is expected in answer to a question of **Have I done something wrong?**  is an answer where you actually point out what and where the OP did something wrong. You are relatively new, so no downvote. Just try and remember the OP has come here for help on a specific question. An answer should provide the specific help sought.

Comment: MD-11 I havn't understood why if we want to get third digit from right side, we use n = 10 and exp = 10^2.Could you explain it further to me?

Comment: This has to do with how / and % operations work - division by 10^x results in x digits from right being cut off. Example: 54321 / 1 = 54321, 54321 / 10 = 5432, 54321 / 100 = 543, 54321 / 1000 = 54. Modulo gives us last digit of a number. Example: 54321 % 10 = 1, 5432 % 10 = 2, 543 % 10 = 3. When you combine these operations you can get consecutive digits of a number.

Comment: @MD-11 I edited my post.. Could you take a look at it?

Answer (score 1):

It took a bit of time to pick though your `countSort` routine and attempt to determine just what it was you were doing compared to a normal `radix` sort. There are some versions that split the iteration and the actual sort routine which appears to be what you attempted using both `countSort` and `sort` functions. However, after going though that exercise, it was clear you had just missed including necessary parts of the sort routine. After fixing various compile/declaration issues in your original code, the following adds the pieces you overlooked.

In your `countSort` function, the size of your `count` array was wrong. It must be the size of the `base`, in this case `10`. (you had `5`) You confused the use of `exp` and `base` throughout the function. The `exp` variable steps through the powers of `10` allowing you to get the value and position of each element in the array when combined with a `modulo base` operation. You had `modulo n` instead. This problem also permeated you loop ranges, where you had a number of your loop indexes iterating over `0 < n` where the correct range was `0 < base`.

You missed **finding the maximum value in the original array** which is then used to **limit the number of passes through the array** to perform the sort. In fact all of your existing loops in `countSort` must fall within the outer-loop iterating `while (m / exp > 0)`. Lastly, you omitted a increment of `exp` within the outer-loop necessary to applying the sort to each element within the array. I guess you just got confused, but I commend your effort in attempting to rewrite the sort routine and not just copy/pasting from somewhere else. (you may have copied/pasted, but if that's the case, you have additional problems...)

With each of those issues addressed, the sort works. Look though the changes and understand what it is doing. The `radix sort/count sort` are `distribution sorts` relying on where numbers occur and manipulating indexes rather than comparing values against one another which makes this type of sort awkward to understand at first. Let me know if you have any questions. I made attempts to preserve your naming convention throughout the function, with the addition of a couple that were omitted and to prevent hardcoding `10` as the base.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void prnarray (int *a, int sz);

void countSort (int arr[], int n, int base)
{
    int exp = 1;
    int m = arr[0];
    int output[n]; 
    int count[base];
    int i;

    for (i = 1; i < n; i++)                 /* find the maximum value           */
        m = (arr[i] > m) ? arr[i] : m;

    while (m / exp > 0)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < base; i++)
            count[i] = 0;                   /* zero bucket array (count)        */

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            count[ (arr[i]/exp) % base ]++; /* count keys to go in each bucket  */  

        for (i = 1; i < base; i++)          /* indexes after end of each bucket */
            count[i] += count[i - 1];

        for (i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--)        /* map bucket indexes to keys       */
        {
            output[count[ (arr[i]/exp) % base] - 1] = arr[i];
            count[(arr[i]/exp)%n]--;
        }

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)             /* fill array with sorted output    */
            arr[i] = output[i];

        exp *= base;                        /* inc exp for next group of keys   */
    }    
}

int main (void) {

    int arr[] = { 10, 6, 8, 2, 3 };
    int n = 5;
    int base = 10;

    printf ("\n The original array is:\n\n");
    prnarray (arr, n);

    countSort (arr, n, base);

    printf ("\n The sorted array is\n\n");
    prnarray (arr, n);

    printf ("\n");

    return 0;
}

void prnarray (int *a, int sz)
{
    register int i;
    printf ("  [");
    for (i = 0; i < sz; i++)
        printf (" %d", a[i]);
    printf (" ]\n");
}
```

**output:**

```
$ ./bin/sort_count

 The original array is:

  [ 10 6 8 2 3 ]

 The sorted array is

  [ 2 3 6 8 10 ]
```